# Reactjs. Multiple data loading when calling the API

Tags: reactjs

When calling the API to fetch the products, the result is fine, since it shows me all the products on the screen,
but in the console I see that the data is called multiple times.
In console the console.log prints 6 times on load and reload page.

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const products = useGetProducts(`${API}?limit=5&offset=1`);
  
  console.log("products: ", products);

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <ProductItem product={product} key={product.id} />
        ))}
      </div>      
    </section>
  )
}



const useGetProducts = (API) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios(API);
      setProducts(response.data)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return products;
}
```

Comment: Anything in the component hierarchy could be causing this component to re-render.  Are you observing that it actually calls the API multiple times?  Or are you observing that it just logs to the console multiple times?

Comment: I´m observing that it just logs to the console 6 times.
And the API is called 2 times.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem?  Components re-render in React for a variety of reasons.  And in the code for your component you log data to the console on render.  Are you asking why the component is re-rendering?  For that, please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as the re-rendering may be caused by something further up the component hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all maybe you have <strict.mode> wrapping your application which occurs multi renders.
Then it's preferable to have the apiUrl in the array dependencies of useEffect, so try this :

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const products = useGetProducts(`${API}?limit=5&offset=1`);
  
  console.log("products: ", products);
  if (!products?.length) {
    return <div>No products found!</div>;
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <ProductItem product={product} key={product.id} />
        ))}
      </div>      
    </section>
  )
}



const useGetProducts = (API) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = useCallBack(async() => {
      const response = await axios.get(API);
      setProducts(response.data);
    }, [API]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return products;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 

Disabling Strict mode works fine.
I have this error message : useGetProducts.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: useCallBack is not defined

Comment: just import useCallback from react like you do for useState :
`import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';`

Answer (score 0):

Use dependencies inside useEffect so that it will only render onetime when data is fetched also use return statement at the end of useEffect.

Comment: thanks, any help with code?

Answer (score 0):

Something is making your component render more than once, repeating the API fetch. UseEffects' second argument can make the code only execute when certain variables are updated, try using it.

Comment: thanks, any help with code?

Comment: @alejandro when do you want to fetch the data?

Comment: I think when loading the home components wich has the <ProductList> component who is in charge of loading the data